# Spring-MVC Jackson not reading the JSON Object from JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc, jackson

Using Jackson I can able to convert the object to JSON

```
@RequestMapping(value="getMessage.test", headers = "Accept=application/json" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody TestObject getMessage(){
        TestObject object=new TestObject();
        object.setMessage("Hello JQuery");
        return object;
    }
```

The above code works well... But conversion from JSON to Object gives **WARN  PageNotFound - No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/setMessage.test', method 'POST', parameters map[[empty]]** Below is the code. Where i am going  wrong..

```
@RequestMapping(value="setMessage.test", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json"  )
    public void setMessage(@RequestBody TestObject test,HttpServletRequest request){
        System.out.println("Inside setting message");
        System.out.println(test.getMessage());
    }
```

JQuery Ajax calls...

```
 $.ajaxSetup({   contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8" }); 

    $.post('getMessage.test',function(response) {  
        alert(response.message);
           }, 'json');  

    $.post( 'setMessage.test', {message: 'Hello Spring'});
```

Comment: Works if i post with callback function $.post( 'setMessage.test', {message: 'Hello Spring'},function(response) { alert(response.message); }, 'json'); But i get org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unexpected character ('m' (code 109)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') **What is sent is not a valid JSON?**

Comment: have you tried `{"message": "Hello Spring"}` insted of  `{message: "Hello Spring"}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the fix. There is a bug in JQuery $.post method which is not setting the proper contenttype. So setting the contenttyple in the ajaxsetup works well... and i used jquery.json-2.3.min.js to create a json object.....

```
$.ajaxSetup({   
           contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    });
```